# Need to create httpwebrequest for sending api post in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried to create a httpwebrequest for post request to api site. The header details below;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUZ1k.png)

and I have tried below code;

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.etc.com/c/search");
            //webRequest.Credentials = cache;
            //webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

            //header description
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Connection = "keep-alive";
            //webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"contains\":true,\"empName\":RAGS TO RACHES,\"injuryDate\":04/13/2018,\"state\":UT,\"stCd\":43}");
            webRequest.Accept = "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9";
            webRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            webRequest.Referer = "https://www.etc.com/c/search";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5");
            //webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

            using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
```

Not getting resposne.

Comment: _"Not getting resposne"_ - well kinda missing the code for it aren't you?

Comment: Can you check that api URL is fine or not , you can test using POSTMAN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

Comment: MD search the duplicate for `request.GetResponse();` to see what you're missing.

Comment: By the way, I removed your Gecko tag because it's completely unrelated to your question. The same for your winforms tag.

Comment: @MickyD What? I'm confused. I never said you were...

Comment: @john oh lol we had the same initials.  all's good :)

Comment: @MickyD Oh I see :-)